# Recommended partitioning scheme for Arch Linux when using two hard drives

Tags: arch-linux, partition, ssd

I want to install [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) on my laptop, which has two hard drives: a 25GB SSD and a 700GB HDD.

I'd like to have the OS installed on SSD and have my data stored on the HDD.

Which partitioning scheme should I use?

Answer (score 1):

SSD: Very fast, limited number of writes.

Hard drive: Slower, unlimited writes.

So, I would recommend putting system software on the SSD. It won’t
change very often, and the fast reads will save you time when you boot
and when you run programs for the first time. (Not so much for
subsequent runs, since they’ll be cached anyway.)

```
/ (including /bin, /sbin, /etc)
/usr
/boot if you have one
```

For the hard drive: swap, of course; data; anything that will change
often.

```
swap
/home
/tmp
/var
```

In particular, be sure to use separate partitions for `/tmp` and `/var`,
or they’ll end up on the same partition as `/`, meaning the SSD.

Comment: +1 although "unlimited writes" is just not true. SSDs may allow fewer writes per cell than HDDs overall, but they also include built-in write balancing and error detection, which is not a given in HDDs.

Comment: I am pretty sure Arch  uses a tempos ram drive for /tmp, so creating a partition is probably the wrong way to go.

Comment: @StrongBad - yeah. it mounts `/tmp` as tmpfs by default. and swap is usually a waste anyway.

Comment: I mean, has anyone reached the cap using ssd for a desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a 25gb SSD and a 700gb HDD?

In that case, you should partition everything as if you only had the 700gb HDD, and use a tool like bcache to cache frequently accessed content to the SSD.

It should provide better performance then putting a traditional file system directly on the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to dual-boot into Windows, just format your SSD as `/` and your HDD as `/home`, or something.

Comment: and what about other partitons like /boot, /var, /usr, etc?

Comment: `/boot`, `/var`, `/usr`, etc., don't need to be partitions — if you don't specify otherwise, they will be directories on the root partition.  I believe that's what this answer is suggesting.  It is also implying that there is no one scheme that you *have to* use.  You can try this one; it will probably work.  Or you can do some analysis on how you expect to use the system and devise a scheme that's better for your situation.